# Difference between input and a in modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a mvc modal dialog. When user clicks on the modal button, I make a Ajax call to load the dialog content. When user clicks on the "Update" button on the modal dialog, I made another Ajax call to update database and dismiss the dialog. I found an issue on the "Update" button in my modal dialog.

If I'm using "a" for the update button,

```
    <a href="#" id="partDialogSubmit" class="btn btn-success btn-block"> <span>Update</span>  </a>
```

Everything works perfectly.

But if I use "input"

```
    <input type="submit" id="partDialogSubmit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Update" />
```

It redirect me to some url doesn't exists. It looks like some cache from my previous Ajax call when the modal is about to show.

Why the behavior is different?

Here is my modal popup script:

```
var showPartDialog = function(partID, modalBodyDiv, modalTag)
{
var url = "/Part/ShowPartDialog?Id=" + partID;
$("#partModalBodyDiv").load(url, function () {
    $(modalTag).modal("show");
})
}
```

Here is my modal sumbit script:

```
$("#partDialogSubmit").click(function () {
    var myformdata = $("#partDialogForm").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Part/UpdatePart",
        data: myformdata,
        success: function () {
            window.location.href = "/Part/Index";
        }
})
```

When using "input", it always trying to load "ShowPartDialog" which doesn't exist

Any hint will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Your input element isn't *just* a button, it is a *submit* button. If it's inside a form element then clicking it will submit the form, causing the page to reload/redirect. Try `type="button"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Fist difference between link and input that I think of is that input can fire default form behavior. Maybe e.preventDefault() could help. Just guessing...